# Counting different input values, add them and show result

Tags: javascript

I want to make a "drink counter". There are 3 inputs which add another drink  `onclick`. Every drink has a specific value in alcohol (`var bier`, `var wein`, `var soju`).

So on every count up (click), the script is supposed to:

1. count up the `value` in the respective `input` [this works]
2. add up all the numbers and drinks multiplied by their alcohol value, so `added_up = bier_full + soju_full + wein_full;`

If you look at the code, you will notice that I'm quite the noob. Help would be much appreciated. I can't think of a way to add all the drinks*alc. values up and display them in the `id="status"`.

HTML:

```js
var full = 100;
var bier = 12.7;
var wein = 10;
var soju = 3.5;

status = document.getElementById("status");

var bier_c = parseInt(document.getElementById("beer").value);
var soju_c = parseInt(document.getElementById("soju").value);
var wein_c = parseInt(document.getElementById("wine").value);

var bier_i = document.getElementById("bier_info");
var soju_i = document.getElementById("soju_info");
var wein_i = document.getElementById("wein_info");

function reset() {
  bier_c = 0;
  soju_c = 0;
  wein_c = 0;
  document.getElementById("beer").value = "0";
  document.getElementById("soju").value = "0";
  document.getElementById("wine").value = "0";
};

function bier_s() {
  bier_c++;
  document.getElementById("beer").value = bier_c;
  bier_full = bier_c * bier;
  bier_i.innerHTML = bier_full;
  return bier_full;
};

function soju_s() {
  soju_c++;
  document.getElementById("soju").value = soju_c;
  soju_full = soju_c * soju;
  soju_i.innerHTML = soju_full;
  return soju_full;
};

function wein_s() {
  wein_c++;
  document.getElementById("wine").value = wein_c;
  wein_full = wein_c * wein;
  wein_i.innerHTML = wein_full;
  return wein_full;
};

added_up = bier_full + soju_full + wein_full;

alert(added_up);
```

```html
<label>Beer</label><input id="beer" type="button" style="width: 50px;" onclick="bier_s();" value="0">
<label>Soju</label><input id="soju" type="button" style="width: 50px;" onclick="soju_s();" value="0">
<label>Wine</label><input id="wine" type="button" style="width: 50px;" onclick="wein_s();" value="0">
<br/>

<h2 class="c_red" id="status">Let's go!</h2>

<div class="am_info">
  <p>Bier: <span id="bier_info"></span></p>
  <p>Soju: <span id="soju_info"></span></p>
  <p>Wine: <span id="wein_info"></span></p>
</div>
```

Comment: FYI - I removed lots of unneeded CSS in the snippet, and then "tidied" it (next time you can also, using the Tidy button)

Comment: Thank you, new to this. Will do in the future!

Comment: That code just says `ReferenceError: bier_full is not defined`.

Comment: @melpomene That could be in part what OP is struggling with

Comment: Then OP needs to figure out a single, concrete question to ask.

Comment: It is not clear to me what is the problem, but I'll try to help. You have some functions and some direct assignment to variables on your example. When you call the `wien_s` the `wein_c` will be incremented inside the function, but the `added_up` is already assigned (outside the function) and the value will remain the same. Is this your problem?

Comment: Yes, I think that was the problem which Luis felipe De jesus Munoz solved by adding the other method!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just add a method that runs every time the other methods runs =D

```js
var full = 100;
var bier = 12.7;
var wein = 10;
var soju = 3.5;

var bier_full = 0, soju_full = 0, wein_full = 0;

status = document.getElementById("status");

var bier_c = parseInt(document.getElementById("beer").value);
var soju_c = parseInt(document.getElementById("soju").value);
var wein_c = parseInt(document.getElementById("wine").value);

var bier_i = document.getElementById("bier_info");
var soju_i = document.getElementById("soju_info");
var wein_i = document.getElementById("wein_info");

function reset() {
  bier_c = 0;
  soju_c = 0;
  wein_c = 0;
  document.getElementById("beer").value = "0";
  document.getElementById("soju").value = "0";
  document.getElementById("wine").value = "0";
};

function bier_s() {
  bier_c++;
  document.getElementById("beer").value = bier_c;
  bier_full = bier_c * bier;
  bier_i.innerHTML = bier_full;
  addUp()
  return bier_full;
  
  
};

function soju_s() {
  soju_c++;
  document.getElementById("soju").value = soju_c;
  soju_full = soju_c * soju;
  soju_i.innerHTML = soju_full;
  addUp()
  return soju_full;
};

function wein_s() {
  wein_c++;
  document.getElementById("wine").value = wein_c;
  wein_full = wein_c * wein;
  wein_i.innerHTML = wein_full;
  addUp()
  return wein_full;
};

function addUp(){
  added_up = bier_full + soju_full + wein_full;

  alert(added_up);
}
```

```html
<label>Beer</label><input id="beer" type="button" style="width: 50px;" onclick="bier_s();" value="0">
<label>Soju</label><input id="soju" type="button" style="width: 50px;" onclick="soju_s();" value="0">
<label>Wine</label><input id="wine" type="button" style="width: 50px;" onclick="wein_s();" value="0">
<br/>

<h2 class="c_red" id="status">Let's go!</h2>

<div class="am_info">
  <p>Bier: <span id="bier_info"></span></p>
  <p>Soju: <span id="soju_info"></span></p>
  <p>Wine: <span id="wein_info"></span></p>
</div>
```

Comment: that does it! thanks a lot. just a small follow up question: it only starts adding the values up after I clicked on each of the input. I guess this is because there is no `bier_full`, `wein_full` or `soju_full` before I hit each of them, so the `addUp()` function doesn't work?

Comment: @sojutyp Exactly. As there is no data about those variables it doesn't work. In fact, the error that you code had before was because those variables were not defined. I solved it with `var bier_full = 0, soju_full = 0, wein_full = 0;`

Comment: Thanks so much buddy!